# How do I perform a TukeyHSD like test on a GLM in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to analyse a glm I created in R and what I'd like to do is get a pairwise comparison of which of my factors are significantly difference from eachother similar to the TukeyHSD test for Anovas. However I have been told that TukeyHSD does not work for GLM's. After doing some research I've found a couple of options and I'm not sure which one is correct or applicable those are the glht or contrast commands.

Here is the code for the GLM.

```
glm.mod <- glm(as.numeric(Ostra..Avg.body.size) ~ as.factor(Macrophytes)*as.factor(Leaves)*as.factor(MacrophyteintLeaves) = 'gaussian', data = main)
```

The body size variable is what I expect to change based on my factors of Macrophytes (which is the presence/absence of species of macrophyte with the options Without for none, C or E for different species). and the leaves have three options of without, q1 , q2 )

Here is an example of what my data looks like (with made up values)

```
Macrophyte  Leaves  Animals CODE    Ostra. Avg body size
Without     Q1        N       1     11000
E           Q2        Y         2   11853
C           without     N     3     13422
Without     Q1          Y     4     13838
```

How would I get an output that shows me if there is an effect for example

without Macrophytes Q1 Leaf - without Macrophytes Q2 leaf (Then a value denoting if they have are significantly different from each other such as a p value).

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.If there is any important info I have missed please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

With a numeric response variable, and one (or several) categorical predictors, I would typically use the following function to get pairwise comparisons of significance for each main effect (for example, Macrophytes alone; Leaves alone) and interaction effects:

```
TukeyHDS(aov(as.numeric(Ostra..Avg.body.size) ~ as.factor(Macrophytes)*as.factor(Leaves)*as.factor(MacrophyteintLeaves)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding :D Is an anova fine for this kind of analysis? or is a GLM more suited?

Comment: Hi Tom, With your dataset, the response variable is numeric and continuous, while the explanatory variable is categorical.  For this particular analysis, (provided variables meet assumptions of the tests) running an GLM and an ANOVA should yield the same results. If the independent variable was continuous and not categorical, then a GLM would be more appropriate. However, with a single categorical predictor, both analyses yield the same results.  HTH, Rob More info: [link] (http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/why-anova-and-linear-regression-are-the-same-analysis/)